# onClick for imported component in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I imported a component from another file. I want to change the state of showModal to true with one click. I wrote a console log in the function to see if the function is running. However, nothing happens in the DevTools. No error message and no log. Is my attempt possible?

```
function Nav() {
  const [showModal, setShowModal] = useState(false);
  const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal((showModal) => !showModal);
    console.log("klicked");
  };
  return (
    <header>
      <div>
        <div>
          <AddTaskBtn onClick={openModal} />
        </div>
      </div>
      <Modal showModal={showModal} setShowModal={setShowModal} />
    </header>
  );
}
```

```
function Modal({ showModal, setShowModal }) {
  return (
    <>
      {showModal ? (
          <div className="modalwrapper">
            <div className="modalheader">
              <button onClick={() => setShowModal((prev) => !prev)}>
                Modal close
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
      ) : null}
    </>
  );
}
export default Modal;
```

I tried a direct function call. But also no error message and no log.

Comment: Is the onClick of the imported component working? Try adding a console log directly within the component's onClick event handler. It's possible that it's not clickable at all due to factors like zIndex. Try logging something directly within the component's onClick event handler.

Comment: @Clytax i tried logging directly with "<AddTaskBtn onClick={() => console.log("hello")} />" no error message and no log. It can't be because of the z-index. I commented out all other components.

Comment: Is AddTaskBtn your own component or from a package? If it is from yourself please add the code to the question

Comment: Yep, looks like `AddTaskBtn` does not support an `onClick` prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you need to attach onClick to a native element, your `AddTaskBtn` component needs to accept onClick as a prop and use it inside of it, for eg:

```
const AddTaskBtn = ({ onClick }) => {
    return <button onClick={onClick}>click me</button>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice, this was the solution. Man sometimes its really confusing. :D

Comment: @fevo2 no problem, you just need to think of components as normal javascript functions and those functions can accept arguments

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide more details about
**Button Component:**
Double-check that the "`AddTaskBtn`" component `(<AddTaskBtn />)` is implemented correctly and has the onClick handler attached. Verify that it correctly triggers the `openModal` function when clicked.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

At first change name of param in openModal

```
const openModal = () => {
    setShowModal(prevShowModal => !prevShowModal);
    console.log("clicked");
  };
```

Also it'll be better to set value to false in modal:

```
<button onClick={() => setShowModal(false)}>
  Modal close
</button>
```

Second issue. Maybe button is disabled or overplayed by any other item. You need to check this too.

This should help